# How to make my Deo-nano work on 100Hz with internal clock?

Tags: verilog

I searched lots of websites to decrease the frequency of the FPGA, but all the coding I found left me with "no clock defined in design verilog" and one of the coding is like this:

```
// generate 100 Hz from 50 MHz
reg [17:0] count_reg = 0;
reg out_100hz = 0;

always @(posedge clk_50mhz or posedge rst_50mhz) begin
if (rst_50mhz) begin
    count_reg <= 0;
    out_100hz <= 0;
end else begin
    if (count_reg < 249999) begin
        count_reg <= count_reg + 1;
    end else begin
        count_reg <= 0;
        out_100hz <= ~out_100hz;
    end
  end
end
```

but I could not simulate the result and get the waveform, does anyone have a solution to this? Do I have to setup the clock in the Quartus II ver 13.0? 
Sorry, but I am new to this verilog programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need hook up the **posedge clk_50mhz to the internal oscillator of the FPGA** device you are using. Normally the vendor will supply you will convenient tools that you can do this with and that will generate the appropriate code.

In your case this could be for example be the tool *"Quartus Prime Lite Edition"* and the document *"Quartus Prime Standard Edition Handbook Volume 1: Design and Synthesis"* at chapter *"Resource Property Editor"* would probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is not a proper module. If the code is not an excerpt, then looks up how to make that into a proper module.

Assuming you have a proper module and can be compiled successfully, then you must supply all the inputs (including the clock) for simulation. You can do that by using the Modelsim Wave Editor or by creating a "testbench". A testbench is another Verilog file that wraps around the module being tested such that it can supply all the inputs.

For this simple counter, you may use the Modelsim Wave Editor to set up the input stimulus for the ease of getting started. After compilation, launch the simulator, a Wave window should come up. Now you can modify the inputs with the simulus you want.

In the long run, you would want to learn how to use testbench if you are going to design and simulate anything complicated (almost by definition, anything that needs a FPGA).

There are tutorials or examples specifically for the DE0-nano, you might want to go through one of those.